# Add Custom Layer to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to apply the custom layer provided by `WeatherBug` for temperature/Radar/Humidity. etc into my google map using google javascript library.

I need to apply the transparant tile over my google map.

I get the tile images from the below url. So how can i bind this into my map?

http://i.wxbug.net/GEO/Google/Temperature/GetTile_v2.aspx?as=0&c=0&fq=0&tx=0&ty=0&zm=1&mw=1&ds=0&stl=0&api_key=xxxxx

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays

Comment: http://lookmywebpage.com/api/google/google-map-custom-overlay-using-javascript-api-v3/

Comment: Thanks Nirav.. But i am trying to add a layer from the WeatherBug provider. We can retrive the tile layer from this provider using a url that they provide. So can you please help me out in doing this..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add this as a Google Custom Map Type. Basically when requesting the WeatherBug API, you get back a tile that you can use on Google Maps.

You can find the documentation from Google Maps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays#Custom_Map_Types).

The code for you to start should probably look like this, you can work on from this point:

```
var tileLayerOverlay = new GTileLayerOverlay(
  new GTileLayer(null, null, null, {
    tileUrlTemplate: 'http://i.wxbug.net/GEO/Google/Temperature/GetTile_v2.aspx?as=0&c=0&fq=0&tx={X}&ty={Y}&zm={Z}&mw=1&ds=0&stl=0&api_key=xxxxx',
    isPng:true,
    opacity:1.0
  })
);

map.addOverlay(tlo);
```

Also check the [WeatherBug description](http://developer.weatherbug.com/docs/Google_GEO_API_Example) and the links in there.

Comment: how do i get the current tile that i have zoomed in inorder to pass the parameters to the WeatherBug url ?

Comment: The TileLayer normally does it itself - see the {X}, {Y} and {Z} parameters in the `tileUrlTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for WMS services inpired by : http://code.google.com/p/biodiversity-imageserver/source/browse/trunk/unittest/gmap3/MCustomTileLayer.js?r=49

You can simply ajust the function for your needs.

```
function MCustomTileLayer(map,url) {
this.map = map;
this.tiles = Array();
this.baseurl = url;
this.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);
this.maxZoom = 19;
this.minZoom = 3;
this.name = 'Custom Layer';
this.visible = true;
this.initialized = false;
this.self = this;
}

MCustomTileLayer.prototype.getTile = function(p, z, ownerDocument) {
for (var n = 0; n < this.tiles.length ; n++) {
    if (this.tiles[n].id == 't_' + p.x + '_' + p.y + '_' + z) {
        return this.tiles[n];
    }
}
var tile = ownerDocument.createElement('IMG');
tile.id = 't_' + p.x + '_' + p.y + '_' + z;
tile.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
tile.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
tile.src = this.getTileUrl(p,z);
if (!this.visible) {
    tile.style.display = 'none';
}
this.tiles.push(tile);

while (this.tiles.length > 100) {
    var removed = this.tiles.shift();
    removed = null;
}
return tile;
};

MCustomTileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl = function(p,z) {
var url = this.baseurl +
          "&REQUEST=GetMap" +
          "&SERVICE=WMS" +
          "&VERSION=1.1.1" +
          "&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF" +
          "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE" +
          "&SRS=EPSG:3857" +
          "&WIDTH=256" +
          "&HEIGHT=256" +
          "&FORMAT=image/png" +
          "&mode=tile" +
          "&tilemode=gmap" +
          "&tile="+ p.x + "+" + p.y + "+" + z
return url;
}
```

You can use it like that

```
var hMap = new MCustomTileLayer(map, "http://my_base_url");
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, hMap);
```

And to delete the overlay

```
map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(0,null);
```